# Print Unknown Length of Table to a CSV file using Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datatable

I have table I want to print out to a csv file using pandas. This table was extracted from a different excel file. The problem I have is that the table length is unknown. How should I print out this table to the csv file to show all of it and not on just on one line

```
for x in ABC:
    print()
    print(f"{x}:")
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(x + "/File.csv")
        df_filter= df[['A','B','C', "D", "E"]]
        if df_filter['D'].str.contains('Fail').any():
            noSC= df_filter[df_filter.DUTId != 'SC_INFO']
            finalTable= noSC[noSC.D == 'Fail']
            if finalTable.empty:
                print("Did not complete")
                sheet1['A16'] = finalTable
            else:
                filterTable= finalTable[['A','B','C', "E"]]
                fullfinalTable = filterTable.to_string()
                print(fullfinalTable)
        else:
            print("Run Successful")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File does not exist")
```

I know that `sheet1['A16'] = finalTable` is wrong, but I unsure what I would do instead of that. It does output the table but only on A16, so it is a long line. Is there anyway to have the unknown table formatted into the new excel?

Comment: x seems to be the directory the file is in. You will run into a problem with `df_filter.DUTId`, as you have filtered to only have columns `['A','B','C', "D", "E"]` in your table. 
To print out the final table as a csv, just use `finaltable.to_csv(x + "finalTable.csv")`
But please change the x to a good variable name, like dir_path.

Comment: We can help you much better if you tell us about the goal you want to achieve. You seem to want to loop over multiple files, filter them, and then save the dataframe?

Comment: Yes, that is the goal. I am looking through multiple files and to filter them to see what has failed and then output them all into one single csv file. Some files may not be there or some files may have passed therefore will not need a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

dir_path = r"yourFolderPath"
files_list = [str(p) for p in dir_path.glob("**/*.csv")]
if files_list:
    source_dfs = [pd.read_csv(file_) for file_ in files_list]
    df = pd.concat(source_dfs, ignore_index=True)
    df = df[['A','B','C', "D", "E", "DUTId"]]
    if df['D'].str.contains('Fail').any():
        df = df_filter[df_filter.DUTId != 'SC_INFO']
        finalTable = df[df.D == 'Fail']
        if finalTable.empty:
            print("Did not complete. Dataframe is empty.")
        else:
            print("Dataframe written to .csv")
            finalTable = finalTable[['A','B','C','E']]
            finalTable.to_csv(dir_path + r"/finaltable.csv")
else:
    print(f"No .csv files in {dir_path}")
```

Comment: This actually depends on if you need to check if every individual file is empty. If you do not need to check every file, this is more elegant and much faster.